# Edit the default empty value attribute?

Tags: magento-1.7

By default we will show empty value attribute in the frontend – in product detail page (product additional information). The empty Magento dropdown attribute will show as “No” or “N/A”.

This is a solution to hide all empty value attribute :

If you have found “attributes.phtml”, find and replace following coding:

FIND:

```
  htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?> productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?>
```

REPLACE:

```
 getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']); if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && ((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != '')) { ?>  htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?> productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?>
```

I would like an other solution, i will change the default empty value attribute to '*'. I would your help for that. I can't found where i edit this default value.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The values `No` or `N/A` is specified in the block class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Attributes`, to change this behavior you should rewrite this class and apply your own logic.

Comment: just this class ??

Comment: If you rewrite the class and build you own getAdditionalData function that should be enough. It's strange that Magento solved it this way, it would be better to have an option in the attribute to specify it's behavior (for example: hide, show default text or show custom text).